# Java - Remove from single list over nested loop avoiding concurrent modification exception

Tags: java, list, iterator, concurrentmodification

So I have this method that is supposed to find pairs inside a collection, for this purpose I use a **nested loop**. However I always get concurrent modification exception even though I'm using an iterator. I guess as **both iterators iterate over the same collection**, they are both trying to modify it at the same time and this is why I get this exception. Can you please help me avoid this error by accomplishing the same results.

```
private List<Pair<Document, Document>> createPairDocument(List<Document> documentsToIterate){
       List<Pair<Document, Document>> pairDocList = new ArrayList<>();
       //iterators are used to avoid concurrent modif exception
       Iterator<Document> iterator0 = documents.iterator();
       while(iterator0.hasNext()){
           Document dl0 = iterator0.next();
           Iterator<Document> iterator1 = documents.iterator(); //returns new instance of iterator
           while(iterator1.hasNext()){
               Document dl1 = iterator1.next();
               if (dl1.relatedTo(dl0) && dl0.relatedTo(dl1)){
                   pairDocList.add(Pair.of(dl0, dl1));
                   //these docs should be removed to avoid creating the same relation again
                   iterator0.remove();
                   iterator1.remove();
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
       return pairDocList;
   }
```

Comment: Can a document be related to itself?

Comment: No. Only to others. But I can have a document A first in the list and B after in the list. I first create relation A to B, but when I find B I create again relation B - A, which is essentially the same relation. I tried only removing B instead of both, but I get the same error. This could be solved maybe by replacing the document with null value in its position and verifying that is not null in each iteration but is not very straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConcurrentModificationException` occurs because when an iterator is iterating through a collection, it has no idea that the collection is modified, so when the collection is actually modified, the iterator becomes very confused (has an invalid state). By using the `Iterator.remove` method, you are letting the iterator know that you are removing elements, so that the iterator can adjust its state accordingly.

In this particular case however, the exception occurs because `iterator1` isn't told about the removal that `iterator0` just did, in the line `iterator0.remove();`. When `iterator1` tries to remove *its* element, it finds that its list has changed.

It's not a good idea to use two iterators that iterates over the same list. I think you can use a regular for loop to loop over the list's indices, and each time getting a *list* iterator *from that index + 1*, since a document can't be related to itself.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < documentsToIterate.size() ; i++) {
    var iteratorFromI = documentsToIterate.listIterator(i + 1);
    var dl0 = documentsToIterate.get(i);
    while (iteratorFromI.hasNext()) {
        var dl1 = iteratorFromI.next();
        if (dl1.relatedTo(dl0) && dl0.relatedTo(dl1)){
            pairDocList.add(Pair.of(dl0, dl1));
            iteratorFromI.remove();
            documentsToIterate.remove(i);
            i--; // so that the next one doesn't get skipped
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now we don't have a concurrent modification exception because we are doing `documentsToIterate.remove(i);` after `iteratorFromI.remove()`, and we are throwing the iterator away after that, so it never knows that we modified the list :)

Alternatively, just use 2 regular for loops.

Answer (score 1):

I would also improve the algorithm and instead of checking for one element all of them all the time try to play a bit with the indexes and base the second loop index(j) on the index of the first one(i). Don't do any removals and use a set in case you think you may have duplicates in the list as suggested already here.

```
for (int i = 0; i < documentsToIterate.size() - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < documentsToIterate.size(); j++) {
        if (related(doc[i],doc[j]);
           addPair(..);
    }
}
```

Comment: Prefer for-each loops to traditional for loops

Comment: Here we need more control over the indices so I prefer doing less iterations

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem could easily be solved when switching from `pairDocList` to `pairDocSet`.

You do not need to remove any element from the list, when you make a Set of PairDocuments. It would be OK to `add` the same PairDocument twice or more to the Set, because there are no duplicates in a Set. You have to make some effort to identify same PairDocuments with correct `equals()` and `hashCode()`, but it is worth.

Comment: Yeah this is a good solution but then I will have to add another condition and I will still have to iterate over the whole collection again even though all pairs have already been found.